# How to solve method not allowed (Post) http error 405

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

### Codes in views

I am new to django I couldn't able to rectify where it went wrong can anyone please help me on this.

```
class UpdateVote(LoginRequiredMixin,UpdateView):
    form_class = VoteForm
    queryset = Vote.objects.all()

    def get_object(self,queryset=None):
        vote = super().get_object(queryset)
        user = self.request.user
        if vote.user != user:
            raise PermissionDenied('can not change another user vote')
        return vote
    def get_success_url(self):
        movie_id = self.object.movie.id
        return reverse('core:movie_detail', kwargs={'pk':movie_id})
    def render_to_response(self, context, **response_kwargs):
        movie_id = context['object'].id
        movie_detail_url = reverse('core:movie_detail',kwargs={'pk':movie_id})
        return redirect(to=movie_detail_url)

class MovieDetail(DetailView):
    queryset = Movie.objects.all_with_prefetch_persons()
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        ctx = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
            vote = Vote.objects.get_vote_or_unsaved_blank_vote(movie=self.object,user=self.request.user)
            if vote.id:
                vote_url_form = reverse('core:UpdateVote',kwargs={'movie_id':vote.movie.id,'pk':vote.id})
            else:
                vote_url_form = (reverse('core:create_vote',kwargs={'movie_id':self.object.id}))
            vote_form = VoteForm(instance=vote)
            ctx['vote_form'] = vote_form
            ctx['vote_url_form'] = vote_url_form
        return ctx
```

### Codes in form.py

I have used this form to link with UpdateView

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from .models import Movie,Vote
class VoteForm(forms.ModelForm):
    user = forms.ModelChoiceField(widget=forms.HiddenInput,queryset=get_user_model().objects.all(),disabled=True)
    movie = forms.ModelChoiceField(widget=forms.HiddenInput,queryset = Movie.objects.all(),disabled=True)
    value = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect,choices=Vote.VALUE_CHOICE)
    class Meta:
        model = Vote
        fields = ('value','user','movie',)
```

### urls.py

This is the url mapping for the view.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from .views import MovieList,MovieDetail,PersonDetail,CreateVote,UpdateVote
app_name = 'core'
urlpatterns = [
    path('movies/', MovieList.as_view(), name='movie_list'),
    path('movie/<int:pk>/', MovieDetail.as_view(), name='movie_details'),
    path('person/<int:pk>/', PersonDetail.as_view(), name='person_details'),
    path('movie/<int:movie_id>/vote/', CreateVote.as_view(), name='create_vote'),
    path('movie/<int:movie_id>/vote/<int:pk>', UpdateVote.as_view(), name='UpdateVote'),
]
```

### HTML template

This is the template I used.

```
{% block sidebar %}
    <div>
    {% if vote_form %}
        <form action="{{vote_form_url}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ vote_form.as_p }}
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" >Vote</button>
        </form>
    {%  else %}
        <p>Login to vote for this movie</p>
    {% endif %} </div> {% endblock %}
```

Comment: Please provide your traceback

Comment: I am getting blank page with this info "This page isn’t workingIf the problem continues, contact the site owner.
HTTP ERROR 405 " Other than this I am not getting any traceback.

Comment: @ToanQuocHo this is the error I got in the terminal. Method Not Allowed (POST): /movie/1/
[29/Sep/2019 07:26:48] "POST /movie/1/ HTTP/1.1" 405 0 full trace back is not showing anywhere

Comment: Are you using anything like this `action="{% url 'code:UpdateVote' movie.id vote.id %}"` on your template code?

Comment: No I am using like this in the form : 'vote_url_form = reverse('core:UpdateVote',kwargs={'movie_id':vote.movie.id,'pk':vote.id})'   This vote_url_form has been used in the template

Comment: How you using it? just `action={{ form.vote_url_form }}` right? Could you also embed your template into the question for more information? Because your form was sent to wrong path so it might cause from your template code

Comment: @ToanQuocHo I have added the template info, could please look at it now.

Comment: Yeah sure, please take a look at my answer below

Comment: and please add the form above and `MovieDetail` view into your question too. These thing has something to do with your question

Comment: @ToanQuocHo I have added the form and movie detail Could you pleas take look at it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem caused because your form was sent to another path which doesn't allow POST request. `vote_form_url` is not which you added in the view context, use `vote_url_form` instead.

```
...
<form action="{{ vote_url_form }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
...
```

---

Btw, your `MovieDetail` view can get rid of `if self.request.user.is_authenticated:` by using `LoginRequiredMixin` like `UpdateVote` view.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I have changed the code as you told but still it is throwing same error :(

Comment: Try to open your browser, inspect the code and make sure the the url look like this: `movie/4/vote/5`, the numbers mean object ids.

Comment: Url is not changing it's still look like movie/1/

Comment: Can you please wait I'm adding form and MovieDetail to the question.

Comment: Just go ahead and add the form and the view of ModelDetail view. Maybe somebody else can also help.. I have to leave here for an hour, will take a look after getting back

Comment: @Sanjay, I will update my answer soon. Please update to this <form action=“{{ vote_url_form }}” instead of vote_form_url